# How do I query for a date in Excel VBA from an Access file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I managed to query eveything from an access file into an excel sheet in the following way:

```
MyQuery = "Select * from TEST"
Set MyRecordset = MyConnection.Execute(MyQuery)
Worksheets("NEW").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset
```

However I'd like to get only those records that have a date in field `BLA4` equal to `31/12/9999`

I tried the following but that did not work

```
MyQuery = "Select * from TEST where [BLA4] = '31/12/9999'"
```

I also tried this but again, nothing found

```
dsDate = DateSerial(9999, 12, 31)
MyQuery = "Select * from TEST where BLA4 = " & dsDate
```

Below an example of the data:

[image]

Comment: Try `#` delimiter instead of apostrophe.

Comment: That solved it, Thank you June7